# Windows Registry creating users

Tags: backup, windows-xp, windows-registry

can i create local users just using windows registry? i write the programm wich help me to migrate my from one computer to another. When i work with domain user i can save it settings with windows registry and saving ProfileImagePath folder. now i want to save local users by this way.

Answer (score 3):

No, you need more than the registry in order to create a user.  You have to script it or use another language that can interact with something like WMI to create users.  Some profile items and settings are stored in the registry, but you also have things like the user's profile folder (including the ntuser.dat file) and the password which are not part of the registry.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList it contains info about all user's profile folder

Comment: And the password resides in the systems SAM file, typically found at C:\Windows\System32\config\. This file is locked down to all but the SYSTEM account I believe.

Comment: ...and trying to edit it manually would be a **Very Bad Thing** (TM)

Answer (score 3):

With a little VBS scripting you can do this (copied from [here](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/usersgroups/localusers/#CreateLocalUser.htm)):

```
strComputer = "MyComputer"
Set colAccounts = GetObject("WinNT://" & strComputer & "")
Set objUser = colAccounts.Create("user", "Admin2")
objUser.SetPassword "test"
objUser.SetInfo
```

Note: you do not interact with the registry at all, instead with the SAM.

Comment: good script but i want to transferred domain user applications setting from one computer to another.

Comment: @Xaver: Please update the question then. Because moving a domain user's profile is a completely different thing (for a start, you don't *create* a user).

Comment: i write the 2 scripts for domain user. First save folder settings of domain user. Second load folder settings to domain user, if settings folder is not exist the script not working.